# how to set the content length and widgth of generating the xml file from oracle table

Tags: oracle11g

Here is the code I am using:

```
SET PAGES 0;
SET LINES 1000; 
SET LONG 999999999;
SPOOL C:\RAMESH.XML;
SELECT DBMS_XMLGEN.GETXML('SELECT * FROM DATAAG') FROM DUAL;
SPOOL OFF;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the set long defines how much CLOB type output will spool for a given row.

you should also alias the column like:

```
col foo format a60000
SELECT DBMS_XMLGEN.GETXML('SELECT * FROM DATAAG') foo FROM DUAL;
```

the `a<width>` sets the column width.

Comment: hi dazzal how to set the column format maximum.. because after the particular length the xml tag cut so i had problem

Comment: @user1999281 do you mean the output was over 1000 characters wide (as your linesize you had set to 1000) for a given element? if so have you tried increasing your `lines 1000`? (im assuming your xml is indented with carriage returns)